# jQuery slider jumps on it's own to different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery UI slider that is basically checking if the user has entered data and then shows an alert if they haven't. The problem is, the alert is showing up fine but when I press close on the alert box the slider jumps to another random value and the alert box shows again. There seems to be no pattern to this.

Any input will be greatly appreciated, the code is as follows:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

        jQuery("button.compareLoans").hide();
        jQuery("p.toBorrow").hide();

        jQuery( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:2000,
      min: 100,
      max: 10000,
      step: 100,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {

        if( !$( "#age" ).val() ) {
          alert("Please Enter Your Age");
        }

        else if ( !$( "#name" ).val() ) {
          alert("Please Enter Your Name");
        }

        else if ( !$( "#email" ).val() ) {
          alert("Please Enter Your Email");
        }

        else {

            jQuery( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
          jQuery( "p.loanSummary" ).text("Searching for loan amount €" + ui.value);

          jQuery("button.compareLoans").show();
          jQuery("p.toBorrow").show();

        jQuery(".userData").fadeOut("slow");

       jQuery.post(
        MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : "myajax-submit",
            postID : MyAjax.postID,
            postCommentNonce : MyAjax.postCommentNonce,
            amount : $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ),
            age : $( "#age" ).val(),
        },
        function( response ) {
            $("#content_update").html(response);
        }
    );

    }

      }
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you replicated your problem over Fiddle or so where we had HTML or a slider to help you.

Comment: Done https://jsfiddle.net/ro03gpf2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slide event gets triggered multiple times while moving the slider. So if you move the slider it gets triggered a first time, you cancel the alert and it gets triggered immediately again.

You may want to look at the stop - event instead: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop

It's only triggered once the user releases the slider.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine - question, when showing one of the alerts, is it possible to set the slider position back to default?

Comment: Yeah. Just add jQuery( "#slider" ).slider("value", 123); after the alert is shown. (Just replace 123 with your default value)